# How do you make python recognize read a precompiled shared file?

Tags: c++, python, cmake, distutils, python-c-api

I have a package I've created in C++ and, have already compiled it into a shared library.

When I link against it with my own main function, I can initialize the package by calling the initialization function directly, initfoo, and everything works fine.

How do I get python to recognize my shared library as a package, so I can just type:

```
import foo
```

running from the regular python interpreter?

I'm not interested in using distutils to compile the file, since the compilation has to be part of the regular cmake build system.  I just need to create whatever package files necessary to load my shared library.

Update:
I now have it working.  The issue was with cmake defaulting to a lib prefix for shared library names.  To fix this requires

```
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(foo PROPERTIES PREFIX "")
```

and for Mac OS X

```
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(foo PROPERTIES SUFFIX ".so")
```

Comment: `distutils` exists specifically because it can a huge hassle to do by yourself (see http://python-history.blogspot.com/2009/03/dynamically-loaded-modules.html) - is building it with `distutils` (possibly twice, if it's also needed in the cmake build) completely out of question?

Comment: It is out of the question.  My commands invoke a lot of C++ functions.  In addition, on Mac OS X, the resulting shared library must link against all of my other shared libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a shared library with `initfoo` symbol exported (note: since you've tagged the question [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) — make sure it's an `extern "C"` symbol, otherwise name mangling will prevent the interpreter from finding it), then it's already a Python module, and can be loaded directly, with no further work. You only need to make sure it's on search path, just like any other module.

Comment: Thank you.  I set the PYTHONPATH variable to $PWD and verified that the "initfoo" function is unmangled, and in the symbol table.  It turns out that the .so file name must be foo.so, and not libfoo.so.  Thanks.